# Exhibition Audio Guide Tour: Text should be present or not

Tags: usability, text

So we are a group of students who are making an audio guide app for a museum exhibition (self-guided). We are thinking of designing the UI (roughly) like this:

[image]

Now, this looks decent but some people from the museum think that text should not be present in the app, since there is already Audio playing. (Text is more or less similar to the audio contents). None of us have a previous experience of designing UX like this.

I personally think that the text should be present, but some members of the team think otherwise.

Can someone with experience guide me on this?
Thanks

Comment: What about people who are not able to hear? Or non-language-natives which might be able to read but not understand the language spoken as easily? I don't know how relevant are these but if such cases exist it might be a point for including text; in case it helps.

Comment: I second that, I think there should be a version for people with hearing disability.

Comment: By the way, is it a pro bono app? Do you need help designing it?

Comment: @Alvaro the app will be installed on museum owned tablets, and we have app in 3 different languages. However, accent might play a role and your point is completely valid. Thanks.

Comment: @DominikOslizlo we are not charging anything for the app. It's for the government and expect some letter of recommendation in return. Help in designing? That'll be awesome. I'd love to see how we can design app for people with sensory disabilities. :)

Comment: Not sure if it applies, but text is also useful for people who are from different countries (you may have different versions, but it is hard to cover all languages) or unfamiliar with the subject matter (and therefore do not know the terms and vocabulary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would suggest:

- have both audio and text version in the app,
- give Users possibility to switch between them.

For people with high level of sensory disabilities, I would even add a BIG FONT / high contrast version.

Answer (score 1):

Loose the scroling text on app start but allow users to turn on the text if they require it. Let the text appear at the bottom of the images. Apply a Dark 50-0% opacity gradient at the bottom of the image when the text aid is triggered. Offer both on and off versions to the client.